# How do I show the set of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ is an infinite dimensional vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How do I show this vector space is infinite dimensional?

> The set of continuous functions $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is a vector space over the field of scalars $\Bbb R$.

This set is an infinite dimensional vector space, since the reals are uncountable. Is this statement the best way to justify this? What is a more complete explanation?

Comment: Since $\mathbb R$ is not a subset of your vector space, your justification is no justification at all. And even if it was a subset, I don't know how you would deduce from that that your vector space is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: No, saying the reals are uncountable is a very bad way to justify the fact that that space is infinite dimensional - it has very little to do with it. For example, the space of all functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ is also an infinite dimensional vector space. What you want to do is write down an infinite linearly independent subset. For example...

Answer (score 2):

The functions $x^n$ are continuous and linearly independent over $\mathbb R$.